# Why am i getting type error children not define for creating parent children relationship from a flat array

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, arrays, json

I am trying to create a parent child relationship between a parent module and the module based on the id, I tried using the below function for the same but seems to be get an error saying children not defined

```
const data = [
  {
    module_id: "96ac027b-b5ce-4326-b5db-5f7b8cab44fd",
    module_name: "profile",
    module_key: "profile",
    module_description: "profile",
    parent_module_id: "8e20f926-2eff-446c-8ad1-23f2a7ae14bf",
    display_order: "3",
    route_url: "",
    component_name: "profile",
    module_type: "menu",
    can_read: true,
    can_modify: true,
    can_add: true,
    can_delete: true,
    can_access: true
  },
  {
    module_id: "a2fc7d41-8fb3-4b7d-852f-342b0bc50be5",
    module_name: "module management",
    module_key: "module_management",
    module_description: "module management",
    parent_module_id: "5470ce5a-341f-4c9f-8f76-a3d696f03c02",
    display_order: "2",
    route_url: "",
    component_name: "modulemanagement",
    module_type: "tabs",
    can_read: true,
    can_modify: true,
    can_add: true,
    can_delete: true,
    can_access: true
  },
  {
    module_id: "abe12d09-5c61-4764-a7ca-c4ec3c0d543f",
    module_name: "user registration",
    module_key: "user registration",
    module_description: "user_registration",
    parent_module_id: "5470ce5a-341f-4c9f-8f76-a3d696f03c02",
    display_order: "1",
    route_url: "",
    component_name: "userregistration",
    module_type: "tabs",
    can_read: true,
    can_modify: true,
    can_add: true,
    can_delete: true,
    can_access: true
  },
  {
    module_id: "c524e207-c532-43cd-b949-2637b8472369",
    module_name: "permission",
    module_key: "permission",
    module_description: "permission",
    parent_module_id: "5470ce5a-341f-4c9f-8f76-a3d696f03c02",
    display_order: "3",
    route_url: "",
    component_name: "permission",
    module_type: "tabs",
    can_read: true,
    can_modify: true,
    can_add: true,
    can_delete: true,
    can_access: true
  },
  {
    module_id: "37c05885-a186-430d-b238-f6c236651085",
    module_name: "change password",
    module_key: "change_password",
    module_description: "change password",
    parent_module_id: "96ac027b-b5ce-4326-b5db-5f7b8cab44fd",
    display_order: "3",
    route_url: "/change-password",
    component_name: "changepassword",
    module_type: "menu",
    can_read: true,
    can_modify: true,
    can_add: true,
    can_delete: true,
    can_access: true
  },
  {
    module_id: "1d528f94-8322-4005-a2e3-0885ddf4c716",
    module_name: "expand icon",
    module_key: "expand_icon",
    module_description: "expand icon ",
    parent_module_id: "8e20f926-2eff-446c-8ad1-23f2a7ae14bf",
    display_order: "1",
    route_url: "",
    component_name: "expand",
    module_type: "component",
    can_read: true,
    can_modify: true,
    can_add: true,
    can_delete: true,
    can_access: true
  },
  {
    module_id: "9542e59e-4b2f-41dd-9619-345eb1c115ef",
    module_name: "permission group",
    module_key: "permission_group",
    module_description: "permission group",
    parent_module_id: "5470ce5a-341f-4c9f-8f76-a3d696f03c02",
    display_order: "4",
    route_url: "",
    component_name: "permissiongroup",
    module_type: "tabs",
    can_read: true,
    can_modify: true,
    can_add: true,
    can_delete: false,
    can_access: true
  },
]
 function createParentChildArray(data) {
    const modulesById = {};
    data.forEach((module) => {
      if (module.module_id in modulesById) {
        modulesById[module.module_id].can_read =
          modulesById[module.module_id].can_read || module.can_read;
        modulesById[module.module_id].can_modify =
          modulesById[module.module_id].can_modify || module.can_modify;
        modulesById[module.module_id].can_add =
          modulesById[module.module_id].can_add || module.can_add;
        modulesById[module.module_id].can_delete =
          modulesById[module.module_id].can_delete || module.can_delete;
        modulesById[module.module_id].can_access =
          modulesById[module.module_id].can_access || module.can_access;
      } else {
        modulesById[module.module_id] = {
          ...module,
          children: [],
        };
      }
    });

    const roots = [];

    Object.values(modulesById).forEach((module) => {
      if (module.parent_module_id) {
        const parent = modulesById[module.parent_module_id];
        parent.children.push(module);
      } else {
        roots.push(module);
      }
    });

    return roots;
  }
```

I am not sure if this is the right way to do it or even an efficent way to do but i would be glad if someone could help me out

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow, as this is your first post here, I would recommend you to take advantage of [the Stackoverflow Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) so this would help you to understand how Stackoverflow works. Also, I would be better if you 
 minimize your code as much as possible and just put the necessary instructions to help us to identify quickly the issue. This would make your question more useful and helpful for others. thank you and welcome again !

Comment: Are you sure it says "children not defined"? Because that would mean that there is a module in your `modulesById` without a `children` property, and that doesn't seem possible looking at your code. More likely, some module referenced in `parent_module_id` does not exist in your data. and you get an error like "parent is undefined"?

Comment: @MoritzRingler so yes i am getting the error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'children') to be precise i am not sure but it working before but now it doesnt

Comment: @sohaiebazaiez Sorry about the phrasing of the question i will try to make the question concise and on point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you are getting the error

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'children')

The only place where you access that property is in:

```
      if (module.parent_module_id) {
        const parent = modulesById[module.parent_module_id];
        parent.children.push(module); //<----- parent is undefined
      }
```

so that means that `module.parent_module_id` does not exist in `modulesById`. This could mean that there are errors in your dataset and you need to replace it. Otherwise, you can probably just put modules with missing parents into `root`:

```
      if (module.parent_module_id && module.parent_module_id in modulesById) { // <--- check if parent exists
        const parent = modulesById[module.parent_module_id];
        parent.children.push(module);
      } else {
        roots.push(module);
      }
```

And that should solve it.

I don't think there is a more efficient way to do it. Though you can write the part where you combine the permissions a bit more readable as:

```
      if (module.module_id in modulesById) {
        const newModule = modulesById[module.module_id]
        newModule.can_read ||= module.can_read;
        newModule.can_modify ||= module.can_modify;
        newModule.can_add ||= module.can_add;
        newModule.can_delete ||= module.can_delete;
        newModule.can_access ||= module.can_access;
      }
```

or even

```
const permissionKeys = ['can_read', 'can_modify', 'can_add', 'can_delete', 'can_access']
permissionKeys.forEach(perm => { modulesById[module.module_id][permissionKey] ||= module[permissionKey] })
```

Comment: Hi I am sorry to not mark this has correct answer, you were right the data set was incorrect it was missing the very top level object which the first parent of the nodes, so thanks for pointout the obvious mistake from my end